# Websocket on localhost (WAMP 2) and running websocket on any free webhosts

Tags: websocket

Can someone explain in detail (along with the directory structure) on how to use websockets on local host? Is there any free webhosting sites that lets you use Websockets rightaway?

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the context of your question, but this is how you can setup websocket communication very nicely: http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial.